# Sign in with Apple test users

Tags: ios, sandbox, apple-sign-in

Where could I create random test users in order to  test "Sign in with Apple" ?
The sandbox users created for Apple pay doesn't work for this too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no "test users" for Sign In with Apple, yet.

You need to use real accounts.

Update:
I had a call with an Apple engineer for during a WWDC 1-on-1 lab.
They suggested a method to re-use the same account for Sign in with Apple.
The downside with this method is that it will NOT return realUserStatus after the first login. Here is the method:

In iOS, go to the settings> Your name on top (Apple ID, iCloud, etc) > Password & security > Apps using your Apple ID > Edit and delete your app.

Now when you login, every thing should work as if it is the first time using Apple Sign In, except the `realUserIndicator`.

Comment: Looks it doesn't work on ios 15

Comment: Thank you for informing, I haven’t tried it on iOS 15, yet.

Comment: On newer versions the flow is `Settings > Your Name > Sign in & Security > Sign in with Apple > Your app`

Answer (score 0):

In apple document not mention about test with sandbox account. So you need to use real account to test.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You can test apple pay with sandbox testing account
the details are here
https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/